# How to avoid scrolling call back in while filtering data?

Tags: android, listview, pagination, searchview, baseadapter

I have implemented pagination with listview and also implemented searchview.For that i have attached customsearchAdpter to listview.
I have overrided onScroll method. I want this method will call when scrolling listview but it also calls when user searched anything in searchview.
I don't want this.
Is there any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this thing via some call back technique.

1. Write an interface with methods like **onSearching and searchingCompleted**
2. Implement the interface and provide definition of the interface methods as if use type any thing in search view **onSearching()** should be called. During this call back duration, remove call back from listview and once searching data is filtered out or searching is done call **searchingCompleted()**. In this call back, attach scrolling listener once again.

Comment: can you elaborate it,i didnt get exactly how we can do this with android.support.v7.widget.SearchView